# Is it breach of contract if dismissed before starting work?

Tags: united-kingdom, contract-law, employment, breach-of-contract

I've been dismissed by a company I was due to start a job with, just a few days before the job was meant to start. They have no intention of providing me with any compensation despite the fact I handed in my notice as my previous job, moved to the other end of the country, and signed a lease at a new property to take this job.

For more detail here is a timescale in which I'll use the abbreviation BCE to mean Before Commencement of Employment.

- 7 weeks BCE received and signed contract of employment with start date.
- At this time I handed in my notice to my then employer and landlord.
- I had little contact with the company or agent who hired me until 3 weeks BCE when the agent called me to check that everything was on track with my move.
- 1 week BCE I managed to secure and sign for a lease on a property in the city the new job was located in. I had to make multiple journeys and incur considerable costs to view properties and find somewhere to live.
- 3 days (1 working day) BCE the agent called me to inform me that the company would no longer be able to hire me because of financial difficulties.
- 1 day BCE I received email confirmation from the company they would no longer be able to hire me and that they were not expecting to compensate me.

It may be of note that I am UK based (I moved from the South coast to Scotland for the job) and although there was a probationary period specified in the contract I am under the impression that that would not have started at the point the employment was terminated.

Are there grounds for a breach of contract here?

---

RESOLUTION:

After giving the company one last chance to compensate me for the notice period (which they refused), I got in contact with my local Citizens Advice Bureau. They recommended I send a Notice of Intent to Sue to the old company, with a detailed breakdown of damages.

In the letter asked the company for reimbursement for my notice period, all moving costs, and first month of rent as damages for the breach of contract. To my relief, they agreed to pay this amount in full, rather than challenging it in court.

Comment: Do you know if they've filed for bankruptcy?

Comment: Does your contract specify some kind of "period of notice"? (Sorry, I don't know the English term). That is, if they _did_ hire you and wanted to fire you the first day, would they have had to keep you for a while?

Comment: Reason I'm asking is because I've been in a similar situation in Sweden, but it was I who "resigned" before the start date. My contract had a 1 month mutual period of notice, and that period was in effect from the moment we signed the contract. If I resigned the day before, I would have had to work for a month. Since I resigned more than one month before my first day on the job, I did not have to show up.

Comment: @pipe it has a 6 week notice for either side to terminate the employment, but there is also a probationary period of three months during which I can be fired without notice. However, I don't believe that probationary period starts until I start work.

Comment: @pipe As far as I know they have not filed for bankruptcy

Comment: "Are there grounds for a breach of contract here" - you haven't provided details of your contract. What does it say about notice periods? In particular my experience of the UK is that most jobs have a probation period with a shorter (sometimes one week) notice period.

Comment: @Chris I mentioned in my last paragraph that, whilst there is a probationary period specified (for which no notice is necessary), I was under the impression that that would not have started until the employment started.

Comment: "BCE" is a somewhat confusing choice of abbreviation since it can also mean, "before common era," which is equivalent to BC as in, "before Christ." I'm sure you don't mean that you were terminated over 2000 years ago. =) Is it an existing common abbreviation?

Comment: Out of curiousity, did you get a resolution for this? If so, how?

Comment: @JackAidley late reply, but I have added the resolution to the question

Comment: @LukeStevens: Thank you for the update, and I'm glad you got your compensation.

Answer (score 42):

UK: For all I know you cannot be fired unless you are hired. They *must* hire you. Once a job offer is made and accepted, they *must* hire you. If they don't, call a lawyer.

I personally know someone who got hired, and when he arrived for his first day's work at the new company, he found that the whole department that he was supposed to join had been laid of. The company had to hire him.

PS. "Financial difficulties" means you call a lawyer *urgently*. Once they are bankrupt your chances of extracting money are not good.

Comment: But, can they hire them, and then lay off immediately without giving a reason, correct?

Comment: @JohnDvorak pretty much, and recent changes in the UK make it much harder to challenge rredundancy if you have less than 2 years employment with the company.

Comment: @JohnDvorak Although there is no basic right to a notice period or right to a general claim for unfair dismissal during the first month (see https://worksmart.org.uk/work-rights/basics/when-your-rights-start), it is still wise for them to give a reason as dismissal on some grounds (e.g pregnancy, protected characteristics, whistleblowing) is illegal.

Comment: You havea typo in "laid of".

Comment: I know of a case with temp agencies you sign a contract, turn up and the person hiring had got fired, so they just didn't bother!

Answer (score 19):

**Yes, it is breach of contract but it is unclear whether you can get meaningful compensation**

According to UK [Government Advice](https://www.gov.uk/job-offers-your-rights), if the employer withdraws the offer after "[t]he employer has confirmed that the job offer was unconditional, or the applicant has met all conditions" then "[t]he applicant can sue the employer for ‘breach of contract’". However, [this advice from the TUC](https://worksmart.org.uk/work-rights/pay-and-contracts/contract-changes/can-my-employer-withdraw-job-offer-if-i-already-have) states that "[i]f a court decides that your contract was breached, it can order your employer to pay you damages or compensation. This is usually limited to the wages you would have earned during the contractual notice period" so you may find that while you can sue the available compensation makes this a poor use of your time.

Consult a solicitor specialising in employment law.

You may also wish to consider simply politely contacting the employer with a list of the costs incurred as a result of their failure to honour a good-faith contract and hope they will do the right thing and offer to offset at least some of your costs.

Comment: This is silly... if the payment ordered is limited to the wages that would've been paid then isn't it always to the benefit of the company to avoid paying you and make you take them to court?

Comment: @Mehrdad As I understand it, punitive damages are rare outside of the US. Court costs and the time and hassle are reasons not to do what you suggest.

Comment: @JackAidley: Yeah I guess...

Comment: @Mehrdad Note that in the UK (pretty sure this applies to Scotland as well as England&Wales), the loser in a civil case pays *both* sides' legal costs (except in a small claims case - and even there, there is the court fee to pay).

Comment: @MartinBonner: Ooh, I noticed it was the UK but I didn't know that part, thanks!

Comment: @MartinBonner: huh. I hadn't realised that didn't happen pretty much everywhere

Comment: @JackAidley In particular, it doesn't happen in the US.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, and even if not there are promissory estoppel issues - hire a lawyer.